# Mounting NAS Storage on ESX

Tags: storage, vmware-esx, network-attached-storage

I am trying to add NAS Storage to my ESX4i but didn't get any option from the VIM Client. It seems that there are less options in the ESX4i than in ESX3.5 so I tried to mount the File system.

I ran the following command
 mount -t smbfs -o username=name //totalstore/dev /dev/

but it says no such device found. The above command worked fine on ESX 3.5.

Comment: Serverfault question to be honest.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to mount storage into the ESXi Hypervisor directly as opposed to making storage available for VM's?

Comment: I have no choice, the VM's that I have to copy on these machine are already so big that they need the NAS to get copied on this ESX. Is there any workaround ? I am new to this, still learning some best practises.

Comment: Doesn't your NAS support NFS? You should be able to mount it as a datastore directly if it can.

Answer (score 1):

smbmount isn't supported on ESXi v4.

Comment: Thanks mate. What are the alternatives ? Can I install the SMB Client on ESX4i and make it work ?

Comment: ESXi doesn't have a console as such (well it does but it's really not something you should be using routinely), there's a limit to what disks it's happy with, it's a short list (FC, iSCSI and NFS) but it seems to cover most people's needs. Can your NAS not do iSCSI? If you don't care about performance you could always use OpenFiler or something similar on a PC to create an iSCSI volume - if you just want to copy files occasionally then you could either use the VSClient datastore browser or the VCLI commands to do the same.

Comment: Thanks Chopper. Yes, I can iSCSI but won't it be worse than mounting. I want to use these VM's to run my test suite's occassionally but I don't want the test's to get completed in many more hours than they would normally do. How bad iSCSI would be ?? Very bad ?? Like I asked before can I install SMBClient ?

Comment: well iSCSI will be about the same speed as you were getting via SMBclient - I doubt you could install smbclient in a sufficiently stable manner on 4i as the 'unsupported' environment is a VERY cut-down *nix system

Comment: iSCSI should be better than SMBClient unless the NAS is very poor but NFS would be simpler and just as quick if it's supported. What model is your NAS?